# SQL, Finding values in column S that map to the same value in column B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a single table with several columns.  The relevant columns are S and B.

```
S  |  B
-------
s1 | b1
s2 | b1
s3 | b2
s4 | b3
s5 | b4
s6 | b4
s7 | b5
s7 | b6
s7 | b7
s8 | b7
```

I would like to get a listing of all S values that map to the same B value  and then count the unique B values:  So the results from the above table would be as listed below and the count of unique B values would be 3 (b1, b4 and b7)

```
S  |  B
-------
s1 | b1
s2 | b1
s5 | b4
s6 | b4
s7 | b7
s8 | b7
```

In an attempt to solve the problem via listing duplicate B values I came across queries that help find duplicates, but that is not exactly what I need.

Can anyone help?

Comment: No, I think it's that a B value has been used more than once to an S value.  B1 is to S1 and S2 wheras B3 is only to S4... So B3 and S4 are not in the results.

Comment: what syntax or version of sql is this in?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your replies.  I'm new to SQL so this is tough to explain.  s1 and b1 are not the same. s1 is not equal to any other s value except for s1 and b1 is not equal to any other b value except for b1.   So s1 != s2 and b1 != b2.  @xQbert: that is correct I am looking for all S (s1, s2) that map to the same B value (b1).  I am using MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

First I would generate a set of data with the distinct counts of each S for each by then join back to your base set of data in source table and limit by the count > 1 from the inline view.

```
SELECT Z.S, Z.B 
FROM Table Z
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT count(Distinct S) cnt, B 
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY B)  Y
 on Z.B = Y.B
Where Y.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Since we now know it's SQL server, Tim's answer uses better features with SQL server.  I tried to write a generic DB agnostic query.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming SQL-Server you can use following queries using the [`Over`-clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT S, B, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY B) AS CntB
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT S, B
FROM CTE 
WHERE CntB > 1
;

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT S, B, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY B) AS CntB
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT CntUniqueB = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B)
                     FROM CTE
                     WHERE CntB > 1)
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d43a/4/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Tim,  I'll give this one a try too.